# Is it possible to make Tkinter remember variables when you close it

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

When i open the program, I want to have the same settings there were when i left.
For instance setting a label to a value and still be that value when i close the program and open it again.
Is this possible in Tkinter?
If so, how would i do it?

Comment: Sure! Just save the settings data in a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) file.

Comment: yes, it's possible. Is that all you need to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the data to somewhere (a text file, `json`, `pickle` or something else) and load it during startup.

So your program may look like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

tk=Tk()
var=StringVar()
Entry(tk,textvariable=var).pack()

# load the text before startup
if os.path.isfile('save.txt'):
    with open('save.txt','r') as f:
        var.set(f.read())

mainloop()

# save the text after shutdown
with open('save.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(var.get())
```